# Retrieving large amounts of facebook 'likes' number into a table?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-like

I was wondering about the feasibility (in terms of speed, etc) of retrieving the amount of likes for a specific thing (website, facebook page, etc) into a table.
For example, let's say anywhere between 20 - 100.
Is this practical? Thank you :)

Comment: Are you trying to get the like id's and users who liked for the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example Assumes you are using php-sdk 3.1.1. you can see the sample here and **login at the bottom**, also **at the bottom is the time it takes to make the graph call** and render it from server side.  *I only have 500+ likes it took about 1700ms to load*.

https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TimeLineLikes.php

---

```
<?php 
echo '<div style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">';
echo '<p>My Likes...</p>';
$i==0;
    $MElikes = $facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=1000&access_token='.$_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token'].'');
    foreach ($MElikes as $key=>$value) {

        foreach ($value as $fkey=>$fvalue) {
        $thisid=$fvalue[id];
            if($thisid==h){}else{
            $i++;

            echo '<div onclick="" class="thisalbum" align="left" style="border: 1px inset; white-space:nowrap; width: 23%; max-width: 23%; height: 86px; margin: 2px; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: bottom;">';
            echo '<div style="background-image:url(\'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $thisid . '/picture\'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:right top; width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: 2px;"></div>';
            echo ''.$fvalue[category].'<br />'; 
            echo '' . $fvalue[name] . '';   
            echo '</div>';
            }
        };
        }
        echo '<b>'.$i.' Total Likes Found</b>';
    if ($i==0){
    echo 'No Likes found. <a href="https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/">Go Back</a>';
    }   
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Hi Shawn. Thank you for the comment! :) However I am trying to do something like a "200 people like shawnspace.com". And I was wondering if I let's say, put one 'like-box' for google, one for my website, one for yours etc etc (and have about 200 or so) if that would cause any problems :)

Comment: I think i might be confused about your request.  Are you trying to get a list of people who like a page/app, or an object?  You can get the number of people who like a page, not the actual people.  Asper an app you can get the people who have added the app, and the number of likes.  For an object you can get a list of people.

Comment: If you are trying to render 200 like boxes, yes i will probably crash the users browser or time out,  
**500ms per call to get number of likes * 200 calls = 100,000ms or 100seconds - at a 30second timeout rule.**  You might be able to use javascript for something like this but it would take some time to make all the calls even if you batch them.